# How to gdb debug into process launched in a child process via execvp?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, fork, execvp

We have two C++ programs, p1 and p2.
p2 forks and launches 3 child processes, each child process calls binary executable of p2 via execvp().
How can I add gdb breakpoints of p2 and debug into p2 when debugging p1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I add gdb breakpoints of p2 and debug into p2 when debugging p1?

You want multi-infefior support available in newer GDB versions. Documentation [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-and-Programs.html).